# more type on a column of an entity in doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I am currently working on parsing my entity files in zf2

I have following code for parsing an entity :

```php
$classname =  get_class($this->object);

$cmf = $this->em->getMetadataFactory();
$class = $cmf->getMetadataFor($classname);

$fields = $class->fieldMappings;
```

it returns :

```
array
  'id' => 
    array
      'fieldName' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'type' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'length' => null
      'precision' => int 0
      'scale' => int 0
      'nullable' => boolean false
      'unique' => boolean false
      'id' => boolean true
      'columnName' => string 'id' (length=2)
  'artist' => 
    array
      'fieldName' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'length' => null
      'precision' => int 0
      'scale' => int 0
      'nullable' => boolean false
      'unique' => boolean false
      'columnName' => string 'artist' (length=6)
  'title' => 
    array
      'fieldName' => string 'title' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'length' => null
      'precision' => int 0
      'scale' => int 0
      'nullable' => boolean false
      'unique' => boolean false
      'columnName' => string 'title' (length=5)
```

I want to add a new type to my collumns. For example for configuring a column is uploadfield or Datepicker :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @type = 'datepicker'
 */
protected $publishdate;
```

and get that datepicker in class meta datas (for creating input elements in zend form)

any suggestion ?

fixed by

```php
$reader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader();
$reflClass = new \ReflectionClass($classname);

foreach ($reflClass->getProperties() as $property) {
    var_dump($reader->getPropertyAnnotations($property));
}
```

and this

```php
namespace Admin\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    Admin\Scripts AS Scripts,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Annotation as Ano;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("PROPERTY")
 */
class sina extends \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation 
{
    /** @var string */
    public $sina;
}

/**
 * A news entity.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news")
 * @property string $artist
 * @property string $title
 * @property int $id
 */

class News extends Scripts\BaseObject 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Admin\Model\sina(sina="sina")
     */
    protected $artist;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. You need to create a new annotation class. Register that annotation with the annotation registry. Then you need to make an event listener for the LoadClassMetadata event, and use a Reader class to instert your extra data into FieldMappings.

Parts of this libary are very unfinished and broken, but have a look at the Readonly directory. It shows how to read and insert a new annotation (in this case it marks a field as Readonly - ie no updates to that field allowed). [SdsDoctrineExtensions](http://github.com/superdweebie/SdsDoctrineExtensions)

Comment: Your solution above does read the annotation, but it doesn't insert the annotation data in to the ClassMetadata->fieldMappings to make it available to other portions of code inside the standard container. The listener is there to insert into ClassMetadata->fieldMappings. (It can be inserted without a listener, but that's more messy and requires subclassing the ClassMetadataFactory.)